# How can you control the serialization of Enum values in HotChocolate?

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

HotChocolate serializes enum values in all upper snail case, which leads to
being the enum value `FooBar` being inferred as `FOO_BAR` by Hot Chocolate, but `value.ToString()` and `Enum.GetName(value)` gives FooBar, and Hot Chocolate seems to ignore `[EnumMember(Value = "FooBar")]`.

How can I change the serialization to any way I'd like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HotChocolate server v11 follows the spec recommendation which defaults to enum values being serialized as UPPER_SNAIL_CASE per default.

You can change this like this:

```cs
    builder
        .AddConvention<INamingConventions>(new YourNamingConvention())
```

```cs
    public class YourNamingConvention
        : DefaultNamingConventions
    {
        public override NameString GetEnumValueName(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
            }
            return value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant(); // change this to whatever you like
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any clue as to why they pass in object and not an Enum to this?

Comment: I want to return the enum description, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do some custom serialization and deserialization of enum values, like using `Description` instead of the `Enum Value` then do the following:

```cs
public enum Colour
{
  [Description("Red")] RedColour,
  [Description("Blue")] BlueColour,
}

public class ColourEnumType : EnumType<Colour>
{
    protected override void Configure(IEnumTypeDescriptor<Colour> descriptor)
    {
      descriptor.Name("CustomColour").Description("Custom colour enum").EnumTypeSerialization();
    }
}

internal static void EnumTypeSerialization<TEnum>(this IEnumTypeDescriptor<TEnum> descriptor)
        where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    var enumValues = Enum.GetValues<TEnum>();
    foreach (var value in enumValues)
        descriptor.Value(value).Name(value.GetDescription());
}
```

You can now register the `ColourEnumType` in the service collection and `HotChocolate` will then correctly return the enum description instead of the value.

```cs
serviceCollection.AddGraphQLServer()
                 .AddQueryType<QueryType>()
                 .AddType<ColourEnumType>()
```

I have tested this on `HotChocolate v13.0.5` and you need to write the code for the `GetDescription()` method.

One last thing to remember though is to make sure that your enum description values are GraphQL compliant. If they arent, then you need to either change your descriptions or sanitize your results during the serialization process. If not, it will cause `HotChocolate` to crash with errors that will be very hard to debug.